# getopts not iterating on shell script

Tags: bash, sh

I'm experiencing an issue with a getopts on a bash script. In particular the code below seems not to work with more than 1 parameter.

If I do:

```
./script.sh - t template-name -m terminal-name
```

only template variable is populated while if i do

```
./script.sh - m terminal-name -t template-name
```

only terminal is pupulated

```
 while getopts ":m:t:r:" optname;
        do
          case "${optname}" in
            "m")
              terminal = $OPTARG
              ;;
            "t")
              echo "Using template: $OPTARG"
              template = "$(cat $OPTARG)"
              ;;
            "r")
              reboot="yes"
              tput setaf 1; echo "TERMINAL WILL BE REBOOTED WHEN DONE!!"
              ;;
            "?")
              echo "Unknown option $OPTARG"
              ;;
            ":")
              echo "No argument value for option $OPTARG"
              ;;
            *)
            # Should not occur
              echo "Unknown error while processing options"
              ;;
          esac
        done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Comment: `terminal = $OPTARG`: Drop the spaces around `=`!

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ and never have a problem like this again.

Comment: Neither `terminal` nor `template` get assigned in the code as shown.

Comment: thanks guys! problem fixed removing spaces

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you are using getopts in a while you do not need the shift.